# How to prevent XSS attacks in WebAPI 2.0 not created as MVC?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, xss

WebAPI 2.0 not created as MVC

What are the security measures that need to be taken care of to prevent XSS attacks in WebAPI? I have gone through the below article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-3.0 but it is representing MVC application. There is no startup.cs. I have this as my Global.asax.cs

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("HangfireConnection");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does not apply to Web API or .Net Core. Instead, you can read the Angular docs about XSS here: https://angular.io/guide/security#xss

Comment: I thought the same but I just want to cross-check. Thanks for the info.